# "Wait for Network to be Configured" startup issue

Tags: networking, netplan

So, this is apparently a common issue - I've even posted about it before myself.  This time, I'm encountering it again and it's not clear to me where the issue lay.

My /etc/netplan/*yaml output is as it should be to typically address this issue:

```
network:
  verson: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
    fake0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
```

networkctl shows that enp3s0 (the interface I use for internet) is configured.  It lists "fake0" as configured and "enp4s0" as "configuring".

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04.

Any tips on where to go looking?

Comment: hey Joel, long time no see